# Why does the ecosystem of my house seem inverted?

Tags: ecology, arthropod, ecosystem, predation

My understanding of a typical ecosystem is that it is like a pyramid, with the mass of prey at the base and the apex predators at the peak.

However, the arthropod ecosystem in my house seems to be the inversion of this.  When I see critters, I mostly see spiders and centipedes, the apex predators.  Rarely do I see anything else.  This seems upside-down.  Shouldn't the apex predators of an ecosystem be relatively rare?

Comment: I’m curious why you think the apex predators should lay low. They’re apex predators. If anything should lay low, shouldn’t it be the prey? Also, there are different ways to remain undetected.

Comment: @anongoodnurse – I guess I'm thinking of something like a jaguar or panther which is very elusive.

Comment: Spiders that use webs are quite easy to spot for humans because they are stationary and they tend to be in the same places. The same isn't true for their preys which, for the record, need not be part of the ecosystem of your house: they can be some animals that are passing by.